# How do I keep Endermen out of my mushroom farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created a nice dark underground room for the growing of mushrooms. Sometimes mobs spawn there but that hasn't been a problem until the Endermen decided they liked the blocks in my walls.

Is there a way to modify a small room which is suitable for growing mushrooms, to be less comfortable to Endermen? I can only think of putting water everywhere so that it will kill the Endermen, but that will also limit my growing space.

Comment: Can you keep them out if the room is only 2-high?

Comment: Is the problem that they're moving walls or what?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Endermen cannot spawn (or teleport, or walk) into an area that is only 2 blocks high as they're 2.9 blocks tall. Therefore, just make sure that the roof of your "farm" is only 3 blocks above the floor. [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Preventing_Attacks)

Comment: Although the other answers are good, this is easily the simpliest solution. My room was 3 blocks high, so I'll just lower the ceiling (or raise the floor). Thanks!

Comment: Worse if it's a giant mushroom farm, which needs to be at least 8x8x8

Answer (score 13):

Enderman [don't like *every* type of block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/what-blocks-can-the-enderman-pick-up-and-what-blocks-cant-they-pick-up/30739#30739): you could just change the walls to something less attractive to them.

If you're playing 1.8.1, you only have a few options, including:

- Snow
- Glass panes
- Obsidian
- Furnaces

But if you play the 1.9 prerelease, fret not: Endermen's penchant for block stealing has been drastically nerfed. If you're building your room out of any normal material people use to build rooms, you don't have to do anything. Enderman will only take the following blocks in 1.9 and onward:

- Cactus
- Clay
- Dirt (grassy and regular)
- Flowers (red and yellow)
- Gravel
- Melon
- Mushroom (both kinds)
- Pumpkin
- Sand
- TNT

Comment: This is the first time I've read about the Enderman reduced abilities.  I'm both relieved the Enderman's they haven't been curtailed too much.

Answer (score 1):

No mobs spawn on halfsteps or glass. So you can use halfsteps/slabs (not double steps) or glass in your walk areas and make sure that the growing areas don't have enough height for the enderman to spawn. You can also properly light and fence in the area outside your building, if it's freestanding, to prevent endermen from spawning inside the fence.

Also with the advent of melons it seems that mushrooms are obsolete as food now, unless you're going to be constantly moving for an absurd period of time...

Answer (score 0):

Just booby trap it for them or lower the roof

Comment: Hi Dean, welcome to Arqade! could you flesh out your answer a little more, what sort of booby traps do you have in mind?