# Can Endermen pick up TNT then set it off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What blocks can the Enderman pick up and what blocks can't they pick up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/what-blocks-can-the-enderman-pick-up-and-what-blocks-cant-they-pick-up)

Can an Endermen pick up a TNT block then place it beside a redstone torch or something and make it explode? If so then please leave a picture or a video!

Comment: Stop with the spam, and do your damn research.  Test it out.  It's not that hard.

Comment: Also, is it just me, or have the last few questions coming from this guy shown little to no research whatsoever?

Comment: more like definite duplicate

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm practically grounded of of everything but the iPod I'm playing on, so it's kind of hard to do research! So I'm sorry.

Comment: The answer is also on minecraft wiki. do some research before asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: **Yes**.

[Take a look at this thread to see what an Enderman can and cannot pickup.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/what-blocks-can-the-enderman-pick-up-and-what-blocks-cant-they-pick-up)

Seeing as an Enderman can pick up TNT, it can place it next to a red stone torch, triggering an explosion.  Try the *Bukkit Mod* to spawn mobs and TNT to test this.