# How do I change a spawner's type in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to change the type of my mob spawners on my server. My server is a vanilla server, as it has no mods. Is there a way I can edit it without mods? If not, is there a mod I can get to change them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

##Method 1: Programs and whatnots
(Please refer to [MBraedley's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/81629/75275) for the main points. This is just an add-on to it/repeating what he said.

The Program **[MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net)** has a mob spawner editing function. Simply left click the spawner with your mouse released.

The **[Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/)** Bukkit plugin allows the changing a spawner type. Just point your cursor at the spawner and use `/spawner [new mob type]`.

The **[NotEnoughItems (NEI)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1279956-chickenbones-mods)** mod allows the spawning of mob spawners with pre-existing metadata. Just spawn one in from the side menu and place it down. *(Note: Does not work without the NEI mod)*

##Method 2: Vanilla Minecraft
With the introduction of the `/setblock` command, and it allowing the choosing of NBT tags...

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> <block_id> <block_damage> <old_block_handling> <tile_entity_data>
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:<ENTITY ID>,SpawnData:{<MOB NBT TAGS>}}
```

The `EntityId` tag within the mob spawner's Tile Entity allows the player to define what entity it spawns. However, if the `SpawnProtentials` tag is defined (and is compounded with entries within it), the `EntityId` tag will have its value changed based on the weights within the `SpawnProtentials` tag.

Not defining one (a `SpawnProtentials` tag) will result in the mob that you have defined to indefinitely spawn.

The `EntityData` tag can be added (is optional) and is used to define the entity it spawns. For example, adding `EntityData:{NoAI:true}` would make everything it spawn not have any AI.

Not defining one will default to the default NBT values for the entity you've defined.

See the [Command Blocks NBT](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner#Block_entity) section of the wiki to see the other tags.
Also note that the data value of the spawner does nothing.

---

You can modify blocks (as [pointed out by MBraedley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/how-do-i-change-a-spawners-type-in-minecraft/197618?noredirect=1#comment267634_197618) with the `/blockdata` command.

Simply look for a spawner and use the following command:

```
/blockdata <x> <y> <z> <new_data>
/blockdata <x> <y> <z> {EntityId:[New Entity to spawn],SpawnData:{[Any mob NBT Info}}
```

All NBT tags found on the wiki can be used here too. Just note that existing NBT tags (that you have not defined) when using this command will **not** get overridden or removed.
`/blockdata` only creates new or changes existing NBT data. It does not delete any.

So, a (let's say Zombie) with `{customName:"Creeper",NoAI:1}` had the command `/entitydata @e[type=Zombie,r=3] {customName:"Zombie",IsBaby:1}` executed on him.
The resulting mob will still have the NoAI tag. (Results in: `{customName: "Zombie",IsBaby:1,NoAI:1}`.
**The same principle occurs for `/blockdata`.**

---

Without further ado, try:
*And then place a redstone torch/block/whatever beside/behind/on top/underneath/whatever it..*

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Item,Delay:1,SpawnData:{Item:{id:"diamond",Count:1},PickupDelay:1}}
```

Moar Diamonds!

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Zombie,Delay:1,SpawnData:{IsBaby:1,Riding:{id:Chicken}}
```

Or something from this [little short](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klP_LXqpHmQ).

---

Alternatively, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/197633/75275 (scroll down)

Comment: The `blockdata` command can also be used to modify existing spawners.

Comment: @MBraedley Noted and added.

Comment: 1.13 changed the syntax of all of these commands: 1. the `/setblock` commads are now written as `/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner{...}` instead of `/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace ...` 2: `/blockdata` (and `/entitydata`, which you use for comparison) were merge into `/data merge (block|entity)`. 3: entity IDs are now in lowercase. 4: Entities riding other entities are now specified in a different order: `{EntityID:"chicken",SpawnData:{Passengers:[{id:"zombie",IsBaby:1}]}}` for the chicken jockey example

Comment: Feel free to edit, or create a new answer.

Answer (score 10):

As of 1.8 (Snapshot 14w28b) you can now change what the mob spawner spawns by "using" a spawner egg on it.

Normally mob spawners only spawn

- Spiders (including Cave Spiders as of 1.8)
- Zombies
- Skeletons
- Blazes (Nether)
- Siverfish
- Pigs (when initially placed in Creative)

However, using this technique, you can now spawn any mob you wish, from villagers to Endermen, so long as it has a spawn egg you can use.

Some mobs you should be careful with however, are:

- Creepers, for their natural ability to, well... Explode. The repercussions should not need explanation.
- Ghasts. They can't actually destroy the spawner itself, but they can wreak some havoc on the surrounding area.

Comment: Can Endermen pick up spawners? (I thought it was one of their banned blocks, but I'm going off fuzzy memory.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie [yes they can](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30069/what-blocks-can-the-enderman-pick-up-and-what-blocks-cant-they-pick-up)

Comment: That answer says they **can't**.

Comment: Whoops, read that wrong. I believe I read it somewhere, but it's likely outdated. It would make sense that they can no longer pick them up. Edited answer.

Comment: I would also like to add Creepers have a Spawner.

Answer (score 6):

The answer below, while still valid, is not representative of what's currently possible.  [@aytimothy's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/197618/1351) describes how this problem can be solved in vanilla Minecraft.

---

As @SaintWacko said, there is no way to edit spawners in vanilla Minecraft, even in creative mode.  [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) will let you do this, though.  It's a separate program for editing worlds.  It's probably not the best tool for the job, and you'll have to know where the spawners are that you want to change in order to do the work effectively.  You'll also have to take the server offline while you do the work.  This also assumes you can sit down at the server, or at least get a remote desktop of it, otherwise you'll have to transfer the world to your home machine to do the work.

Comment: That's true, this would allow you to do it while still keeping the server vanilla, although it's not as easy, and you would be the only one that could do it.

Comment: \*poke\* As the accepted answer, care to update to reflect the changes in this aspect of vanilla Minecraft?

Comment: Um.. @MBraedley, I only added on the commands bit since you already covered MCEdit and those sorts of programs.

Answer (score 3):

In 1.8 and later you can use(default right-click) spawn egg on the mob spawner to change the spawner type. This will make the spawner same as vanilla-generated spawners. But if you want to change the spawn properties or do something more advanced, you have to use `/blockdata` command. Check out these pages :

- [`/blockdata` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#blockdata)
- [Command NBT](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_Tags)
- [NBT Format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format)
- [Block Entity Format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format)
- [Entity IDs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values/Entity_IDs)

Comment: Just for information, you can find complete changelog of Minecraft 1.8 here :  http://www.reddit.com/r/edstonehelper/wiki/1_8_final

Comment: /blockdata was renamed to /data merge block in 1.13

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit spawners in vanilla minecraft. The [Spawner GUI](http://www.minecraftmine.org/spawner-gui-mod/) mod will allow you to change the spawner type, as well as being able to pick up the spawner, and disable it with a redstone signal. It require's Risugami's Modloader, but that's pretty common, and actually makes it easier. There is an explanation on the page I linked to, but if you have any trouble, let me know here. I'll be around for a while, waiting for GW2 :D

Answer (score 1):

You can install Too Many Items to set up the spawners, then save the world and move it to the server. The spawner changes don't rely on TMI once you've made the changes, and will stay how you set them up.

There is a specific number at the end of the spawner ID, like for an exp orb spawner (random) it would be `52:2`. (I found this out when I started using Too Many Items because it shows the ID.) For an enderman spawner, the ID extension would be `52:58`.

Comment: Yes, but they cannot implement this on a vanilla server.

Comment: oh i didn't know

Comment: But can I download Too Many Items, then create a single player world, place spawners, then switch the world to a server?

Comment: @ShadowZ. Yeah, that works. The data stays changed in the save even once TMI is no longer running.