# How do you make a Mob Spawner spawn enemies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I change a spawner’s type in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/how-do-i-change-a-spawners-type-in-minecraft)

When I place a [Mob Spawner](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner) in vanilla Minecraft, it seems to only spawn pigs.

How can I manually place a Mob Spawner that spawns enemies?

Comment: What tools are you using?  MCEdit?  Some bukkit mod?  Nothing at all?  These are important pieces of information before we can help you.

Comment: see [How do I change a spawner's type in Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/how-do-i-change-a-spawners-type-in-minecraft)