# How can you get different types of monster spawners in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change a spawner’s type in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/how-do-i-change-a-spawners-type-in-minecraft)

Whenever I use the give spawner command in minecraft, it is always a pig spawner. Is there a way to get any other spawners like skeleton or zombie spawners, or is it permanently pig? Also, what is the address of othe spawner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spawner stores all it's properties in a tile entity, which is why they cannot be moved by pistons.

Using MCEdit you can make spawners with different mobs, and there are filters out there to change the types of entities and change the spawn rate.

Comment: or use NEI which can give you the correct spawner