# What are the IDs for the spawners in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to do /give Nickbrownie 52 1 58
the ID is 52:58 and its supposed to give an Enderman Spawner I placed it and it was a piggy spawner please help me!

Comment: Google is an awesome companion for some questions

Answer (score 6):

Spawners ignore IDs from the `give` command [according to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Monster_Spawner) (emphasis mine):

> The monster spawner is only available through use of the /give command and, if placed, will only spawn pigs by default. At this current time, **even if correct data values for mobs are given when using the /give command, the mob spawner will always be a pig spawner**.

[Changing the type of spawner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/how-do-i-change-a-spawners-type-in-minecraft), right now, requires placing the spawner and then using external map editing tools like MCEdit to customise the spawner's metadata. For details, see this Arqade question about how to change the spawner's type:

- [How do I change a spawner's type in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/how-do-i-change-a-spawners-type-in-minecraft)