# How can I protect my creations from Endermen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I build something out of expensive blocks (like emerald blocks), a silly Enderman walks past and steal a block. Is there any way to prevent this, without ruining the creation (putting water around it, and spamming torches everywhere)?

Comment: put lava around it and spam glowstone?

Comment: @Paralytic Endermen also hate water so a normal moat should suffice.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30069/42984

Comment: no thats no  a duplicate...

Comment: @David Starkey he said without using water

Comment: @Paralytic You are correct, though not sure how Lava is a better option and spamming glowstone is essentially the same as spamming torches.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't solve the "without ruining the creation" but building the creation entirely out of slabs will protect it from endermen.

Comment: @David Starkey guess it wasnt as funny as i thought

Comment: @Paralytic I should have put a smiley on the end of that comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Endermen will only steal naturally occuring blocks (like dirt, stone or grass). Build your house of planks or stonebricks or something similar and you should be fine.

Comment: [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30460/42984) begs to differ

Comment: @DavidStarkey that answer is hopelessly out of date

Comment: @ratchetfreak Then this answer needs a source that confirms it.  At least a newer source then that answer.

Comment: the [MC wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Endermen#Moving_blocks) not good enough?