# Are there any blocks an enderman can hold but can't place

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The enderman, the block stealing/griefing mob in Minecraft, can pick up a variety of blocks. With commands, we can have it hold an even wider variety (all blocks?).

Now my question is: **Are there any blocks which: *can be held but cannot be placed* by an enderman in unmodded Minecraft?**

Comment: I think anti-enderman-grieving datapacks use barriers. But that info might be out of date.

Answer (score -2):

The blocks I'm certain can't be held by Enderman are:

- End Stone
- Obsidian
- Bedrock
- Doors
- Trapdoors
- Stone
- All types of copper

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for. And most types of stone I know can be held by enderman.  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30069/296788 shows which blocks can't be picked up, but doesn't really tell which ones can't be put down. Furthermore, it's kinda old.